# help: where can I find pygettext.py and msgfmt.py?

Tags: python

I am using openSUSE11.3 and wanna use gettext in my app. BUt I cannot find two python utilities pygettext.py and msgfmt.py. Could you guys tell me where can I find them? What's the path? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On my system it's `C:\Python27\Tools\i18n`. It may be similar for you.

Comment: This worked for python 3.11 on Windows but seems to not be included anymore with 3.12 (at least when I installed via `choco install python312`)

Answer (score 0):

Under openSUSE and SLES you need to install `python-demo` and then `msgfmt.py` will be available in `/usr/share/doc/packages/python/Tools/i18n`.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you can install msgfmt.py using pip:

```
python3 -m pip install python-gettext
```

And you can find the location using this command:

```
sudo find / -name 'msgfmt.py'
```

Usually the path is something like /usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/pythongettext.